# Why is Wordpress/my theme resizing and what can I do about it?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am having some problems with image display size in a section ("Why RFM?") of a site I am working on.

The site is: http://rfm-inc.com/.

[Image of problem section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFQbF.png)

Basically, the site won't display the featured image at the size I need. I want all icons to be 90 px tall and whatever the natural corresponding width is.

I have uploaded all images at 180 px for sharpness.

What changes do I need to make to get the display I want? I haven't been able to correct this using CSS, so I think it has something to do with PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe this has something to do with generated images that Wordpress creates when you upload an image. Are there any settings within your theme?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured it out. I was using a plugin call "Features by Woothemes" and there was a tweak to make to image size in the widget itself.